# How do I accept the user input and put it into the while condition

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

This is my code, the while loop does not have an input and the `rep` variable does not accept an input:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MixedData {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String rep = "";
        do {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter your full name");
            String name = keyboard.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Enter your GPA: ");
            double gpa = keyboard.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("Name: " + name + ", GPA: " + gpa);
            System.out.println("Do you want to enter the data for another student?(y/n)");
            rep = keyboard.nextLine();
        } // This does not accept input
        while (rep.equals("y"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Answer (score 1):

Either just add one more `keyboard.nextLine()` before `rep = keyboard.nextLine();` (*in order to clear the newline character*), or read your **double gpa** value with:

```
double gpa = Double.parseDouble(keyboard.nextLine());
```

**Important** point to understand here (especially if you're a novice Java developer), about why your code doesn't work, is, that you invoke `nextDouble()` as a last method on your Scanner instance, and it *doesn't move the cursor to the next line*.

A bit more details:

All the methods patterned `nextX()` (like `nextDouble()`, `nextInt()`, etc.), **except `nextLine()`**, read next token you enter, but if the token isn't a ***new line*** character, then the cursor isn't moved to the next line. When you enter double value and hit `Enter`, you actually give to the input stream two tokens: a *double value*, and a *new line character*, the double value is initialized into the variable, and the *new line* character stays into input stream. The next time you invoke `nextLine()`, that very new line character is read, and that's what gives you an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to skip blank lines.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String rep;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter your full name");
        String name = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter your GPA: ");
        double gpa = keyboard.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Name: " + name + ", GPA: " + gpa);
        System.out.println("Do you want to enter the data for another student?(y/n)");
        rep = keyboard.next();
        keyboard.skip("\r\n"); // to skip blank lines
    }
    while (rep.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
    keyboard.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the same code using a while loop instead of do-while. It works the way you want it to.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MixedData {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String rep = "y";

        while (!rep.equals("n")) {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter your full name: ");
            String name = keyboard.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Enter your GPA: ");
            double gpa = keyboard.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("Name: " + name + ",GPA: " + gpa);
            System.out.println("Do you want to enter the data for another student?(y/n)");
            rep = keyboard.next();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [nextLine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) instead of [nextDouble](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble()):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String rep = "";
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter your full name:");
        String name = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter your GPA:");
//        double gpa = keyboard.nextDouble();
        double gpa = Double.parseDouble(keyboard.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Name: " + name + ", GPA: " + gpa);

        System.out.println("Do you want to enter the data for another student?(y/n)");
        rep = keyboard.nextLine();
    } while (rep.equals("y"));
    keyboard.close();
}
```